# Generate PDF in Memory

Tags: c#, itext

I am using ITextSharp for generating pdf, I have to generate a pdf in memory using MemoryStream(as I dont have to save the file physically). I have generated the stream,but I am not understanding how to generate pdf in memory.
This is how I am generating Stream

```
  private static byte[] GetFileStream()
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        document.Open();
        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<table class=\"table\">");
            sb.Append("<thead>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append(" <th> Crime Category </th>");
            sb.Append(" <th>Date</th>");
            sb.Append(" <th>City</th>");
            sb.Append(" <th>Description</th>");
            sb.Append(" <th>Option(s)</th>");
            sb.Append(" </tr>");
            sb.Append(" </thead>");
            sb.Append(" <tbody>");
  sb.Append(" <tr><td>This is a test</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><tr/>");
            sb.Append(" </tbody>");
            sb.Append(" </table>");
            List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(misdem.ToString()), null);
            for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
            {
                document.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
        finally
        {
            document.Close();
        }

        return stream.GetBuffer();
    }

byte[] pdfByteData = GetFileStream();
var ms = new MemoryStream(pdfByteData);
```

I tried using this but its throwing exception

Token '' was not expected.

```
using (PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(ms, PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
            {
                int count = inputDocument.PageCount;
                for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
                {
                    PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage page1 = inputDocument.PageCount > idx ? inputDocument.Pages[idx] : new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage();
                    //       outputDocument.AddPage(page1);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

just after creating the `MemoryStream`

EDIT:
Also change the way you return the data, I'm not sure `GetBuffer` does what you expect. Try this instead (where you currently have `return stream.GetBuffer();`)

```
stream.Flush();
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(data, 0, (int)stream.Length);
return data;
```

Comment: seems helpful but I am getting Non negative not allowed now :(

Comment: Here
using (PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(ms, PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))

Comment: Just realised you don't use `sb` after creating it, but use something called `misdem` instead - mistake?

Answer (score 1):

4 years later...

I realise you made a mistake in

```
sb.Append(" <tr><td>This is a test</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><tr/>");
```

Where `<tr/>` should be `</tr>`